How can I constrain a draggable SwiftUI element along an arc - without it hopping from one side to the other?
I'm attempting to have a circle that is draggable along an arc (between two arbitrary angles of a circle - the ones I've chosen randomly are between 13 degrees and 272 degrees. I want this to work like a Slider, but along the partial curve of a circle. That means that when the handle reaches the end of the curve, I need it to stop - not to suddenly jump to the other side and continue going.
Here is a SwiftUI View that demonstrates the (broken) effect:
struct DraggableCircleView: View {
    @State private var angle: Double = 13 // Start at 13 degrees

    private let minAngle: Double = 13
    private let maxAngle: Double = 272
    private let size: CGFloat = 300
    private let handleSize: CGFloat = 20

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: handleSize, height: handleSize)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .position(position(for: angle, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)))
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        let center = CGPoint(x: size / 2, y: size / 2)
                        let newLocation = CGPoint(x: center.x + value.translation.width, y: center.y + value.translation.height)
                        let newAngle = angle(from: newLocation, center: center)
                        if newAngle >= minAngle && newAngle <= maxAngle {
                            self.angle = newAngle
                        } else if newAngle < minAngle {
                            self.angle = minAngle
                        } else if newAngle > maxAngle {
                            self.angle = maxAngle
                        }
                    }
                )
        }
    }

    func angle(from location: CGPoint, center: CGPoint) -> Double {
        let dx = location.x - center.x
        let dy = location.y - center.y
        let radians = atan2(dy, dx)
        let degrees = radians * 180 / .pi
        let adjustedDegrees = degrees < 0 ? degrees + 360 : degrees
        return adjustedDegrees
    }

    func position(for angle: Double, in rect: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
        let radius = Double(min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2 - handleSize / 2)
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let radians = angle * .pi / 180
        return CGPoint(
            x: center.x + CGFloat(radius * cos(radians)),
            y: center.y + CGFloat(radius * sin(radians))
        )
    }
}

I think I need to "break" or cancel the dragGesture at the moment it is clamped (where I set self.angle = minAngle or maxAngle, for example). I haven't been able to find any examples where a drag gesture can be interrupted through code.

There will inevitably be "jumps" when you drag through (or near) the center of the circle. How do you want to handle those cases?

Right now, it drags only around the edge of the circle. Let's say I "constrain" it from 30 to 60 degrees. When it goes past 60 degrees, it jumps back to the top at 30 degrees. I want it to stop at 60 degrees, and the only way to get it to move would be to reverse the direction.
